# How do i pass value through action sheet in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

UnitActionMenu(idUnidade) {

```
let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({


  buttons: [
    {
      icon: 'ios-trash-outline',
      text: 'Deletar',
      role: 'destructive',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Destructive clicked');
      }
    },

    {
      icon: 'ios-create-outline',
      text: 'Editar',
      handler: () => {
        this.navCtrl.push("UnidadeEditPage", {id_building: this.id_building._id})
        console.log('Editar clicked');
      }
    },
    {
      icon: 'ios-remove-circle-outline',
      text: 'Cancelar',
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    }
  ]
});
actionSheet.present();
```

}

My HTML

```
          <ion-input type="text" [value]="unit" #idUnidade hidden></ion-input>

    </ion-list>
```

action sheet to perform edit and delete, I am having a problem passing a clicked on value from a list item,  I have  tried everything can anyone help me solve this issue

Comment: I am not quite sure how to implement this method, but here is what i tried, didn't work, can you please tell me something i am doing wrong, that value i want to push is an Array. `UnitActionMenu(idUnidade) {
                
let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({


  buttons: [
   {
    handler: () => {
        this.navCtrl.push("UnidadeEditPage", {id_building: this.id_building._id})
        console.log('Editar clicked');
      }
    },
    {
        handler: () => {
        console.log('Cancel clicked');
      }
    }
  ]
});
this.actionSheet.onDidDismis({});`

Answer (score -1):

use the `onDidDismiss` callback to and do the edit or delete action after the user selects his/her choice from the actionsheet